# How can I use radish with Pycharm to have behave step autocomplete

Tags: python, pycharm, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

Note : radish is a "Gherkin-plus" framework—it adds Scenario Loops and Preconditions to the standard Gherkin language, which makes it more friendly to programmers.
So how i can use it or use an other method to use Gherkin step autocomplete with Pycharm.
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by buying a professional version of PyCharm, autocomplete is not available for Community version :(